# trigger in oracle from view another database to table

Tags: oracle11g

its not working

```
create trigger UNITS_REALESTATE_ADD
instead of insert on UNITS_REALESTATE
for each row
DECLARE
CREATED_BY char := '1';
begin
Insert into PROJECT values (
TEMP_SEQ.nextval,:new.unit_name,CREATED_BY,:new.descDetails,:new.stage_code);
end;
```

Comment: What does "its not working" mean?

Comment: it doesn't work when run this trigger

Comment: Ah, yes, now it is much more clear.

Comment: on UNITS_REALESTATE tis is view and project it table

Comment: That's obvious, simply by looking at code you posted. Feel free to share some useful information. Once again: **what** doesn't work? What happens when you try to insert a row into that view? Is there any error? If so, which one? If not, what is it, then?

Comment: Your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_VG0KN7Z)

Comment: OK ITS WORK FROM VIEW TO TABLE BUT I WANT FROM TABLE TO VIEW THEN WORK TRIGGER TO ADD ANOTHER TABLE OK IN THIS CASE NOT WORK